# npm install exited with status 232

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, openshift, npm-install

i am getting following error while runing the dockerfile on openshift.everything is working fine locally and dockerfile also build fine with podman locally

errorlog

```
STEP 1/13: FROM default-route-openshift-image-registry/node18:lts-bullseye
Trying to pull default-route-openshift-image-registry/node18:lts-bullseye...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob sha256:13cc0cabeebe5fa28f356ba963028cafff6c3877dbcaaf40bec48d8a8c3777d3
Copying blob sha256:5fc3f101581eb40723f2cd658eea360130362d581680e1f2e5898339c5a34593
Copying blob sha256:886bc16efe37c1f4aa799bfa27a33a3b5dbb798e9fe32951c4c4ddb92c380645
Copying blob sha256:c6e441fd555224aa74b134c302d0602bb003e0239d2b01fbe1847a7e848bebe4
Copying blob sha256:46ab6923c62aa8ae7ae953493bce8742eeedfa88fb1dc2e7a5d10dfba42ed5e1
Copying blob sha256:74f0aee12a8a78eaddcc15028463cb41be561dce8d7fefbc51f35df48f480098
Copying blob sha256:9cab4b88d92849dcffae4de0ebc141fe5e81658782ad0eb38d8885c853e9e9fb
Copying blob sha256:c1be4a3cd29f7715085ad919b8747151240f43a567c43425ac72f33db4f91182
Copying config sha256:c40e0caabcca77b360307e9515d00d9308001f93c12a37c5cc641b17f222b6c6
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
STEP 2/13: WORKDIR /usr/src/app
STEP 3/13: COPY package.json ./
STEP 4/13: ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--dns-result-order=ipv4first"
STEP 5/13: RUN npm i
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.5.1 -> 9.7.2
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.7.2>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.7.2` to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code EMFILE
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/21/5c/43bc4bbdabf8ae0454ee7075000f4ba27acf124106cdb71a445723bbc8c9
npm ERR! errno -24
npm ERR! EMFILE: too many open files, open '/root/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/21/5c/43bc4bbdabf8ae0454ee7075000f4ba27acf124106cdb71a445723bbc8c9'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-06-30T13_23_13_610Z-debug-0.log
subprocess exited with status 232
subprocess exited with status 232
error building at STEP "RUN npm i": exit status 232
```

i feel like i am the only one with following error.i don't get any info for following error. may be something i need to clear cache.could i do any command to clear npm cache before runing the npm install.

Comment: Could you please share some details for us to help find the reason? We cannot help much here :/ Maybe try to increase the open file number limit? But I doubt it really is the problem. As for the cache, hard to tell since we don't see all the parts, but you can try clearing it with `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 2):

Docker sets the "number of open files" limit when running commands inside the container.  In your case, this limit is too low, causing the error you see when running `npm`.

To fix, run the same docker command, but pass a new flag: `--ulimit nofile=65535:65535` along with the other flags to the `docker` command.

Example:

```
docker build --ulimit nofile=65535:65535 -t my_container_name .
```